# null value Map entries are missing from the json response in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson-databind

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class Response {
 private List<Map<String,Object>> value;
}
```

Getting ,

"value": [
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
},
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
}
]

Expected :

```
 "value": [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3" : null
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
        "key3" : null,
        "key4" : null
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you done any JSON configuration in spring-boot? I check the class you have provided with spring-boot and it returns null values.

Comment: Yes , Tried this - 
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always